# In Python's imp, "ImportError: No frozen submodule named ..."

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script which searches a directory for a module with a given name. I'd like to use the `find_module` method of Python's [imp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html). However, I don't quite understand why the following doesn't work. I'm in a directory which contains a module `iclib`:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/dev/ipercron-compose/furion$ tree
.
├── iclib
│   ├── __init__.py
```

In that directory I can (in iPython) import `iclib`:

```
In [1]: import iclib
```

I can also use `find_module` without a `path` argument:

```
In [1]: import imp

In [2]: imp.find_module('iclib')
Out[2]: (None, 'iclib', ('', '', 5))
```

However, if I try to use `find_module` in the current directory only, I get an error:

```
In [3]: import os

In [4]: imp.find_module('iclib', os.getcwd())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ada6f3744e78> in <module>()
----> 1 imp.find_module('iclib', os.getcwd())

ImportError: No frozen submodule named /home/kurt/dev/ipercron-compose/furion.iclib
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following this [issue on bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/issue6448), the `path` argument needs to be embedded within a list:

```
In [4]: imp.find_module('iclib',[os.getcwd()])
Out[4]: (None, '/home/kurt/dev/ipercron-compose/furion/iclib', ('', '', 5))
```

With square brackets around the `os.getcwd()`, the function returns the expected output.