# Python imp module's find_module() function always fails with ImportError exception for an available module

Tags: python

```
imp.find_module('my_module', os.path.expanduser('~') + os.sep)
```

*ImportError: No frozen submodule named /home/user/.my_module*

Above code fails with exception even though the **my_module.py** file is available in the home directory path. I could see that there is a dot prefix, the '.' character automatically precedes the actual filename. I am not sure why this behavior is by Python.

Comment: does your home directory contain a __init__.py file?

Comment: I got the solution from here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127133/in-pythons-imp-importerror-no-frozen-submodule-named

Comment: Have you seen the answer where they suggest passing the 2nd argument as a list? Try [os.path.expanduser('~') + os.sep] ?

Comment: Yes that is the solution. you got it right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python's imp, "ImportError: No frozen submodule named ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127133/in-pythons-imp-importerror-no-frozen-submodule-named)